# Running CMD Bat Scripts with IIS Application Pool User

Tags: batch-file, iis, cmd, dnx, windows-server-2012-r2

I have inherited an IIS server running Windows Server 2012 and a bit of a novice with Microsoft server product.

One of the users is trying to execute CMD/Bat files to launch DNX web application through IIS. From what I understand, for IIS to run the script the user assigned to the application pool needs to be granted permissions to run bat/cmd files. These permissions need to be set to the user some how.

Having looked at the standard tools installed on the windows system (Computer Management > Local Users / Group) I have been unable to find any option to grant permissions.

I'm just wondering how secure this solution is? And how to grant the permissions to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things work a bit differently with ASP.NET Core 1/dnx. IIS only supposed to act as a reverse proxy - i.e. the ASP.NET Core application runs in a separate process and is using Kestrel web server as a host and IIS only forwards requests to the appliaction. Take a look [at this article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) which explains how to publish ASP.NET Core 1 /dnx app to IIS.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get to this, this is working (kind of). The steps you provided seem correct, there is a bug in my users code which is holding things up. Thanks for your input though :)